# Load body jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

estaba tratando de realizar esa funcion de carga del body mediante un boton, cuando yo lo presiono quiero que se vuelva a recargar la pagina en vez de usar el boton que se encuentra en el navegador.
Probe con jquery de esta manera pero no me funciona

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function (){
        $("body").load(this); 
     })
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar la función [location.reload()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Location/reload) de javascript

```html
   
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function (){
       location.reload()
     })
  });
</script>
```